# IE select box transparent background

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, sass

I'm having a very hard time getting the IE select box background to be transparent so I can use the background image I want to use for it.

```
.select-style {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid $lightblue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: $white;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: url(../img/select-arrow.png) no-repeat right;
  overflow: hidden;

  select {
    padding: 5px 3%;
    width: 130%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';

    option {
      width: 100%;
      color: $black;
      background-color: $white;
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried everything. Using filters, -ms-filters, backgrounds, colors and background colors set to transparent and using a rgba to get it to be transparent. Nothing is working. jQuery is not an option to use for select consistency so I need to use CSS.

Any thoughts?
Here's what I'm talking about: (you can see the background image behind it)

[image: example]

Comment: What version of IE? (And please add a tag for your CSS preprocessor)

Comment: IE9+ it's happening all the way up to 11.

Comment: Does it work if you add `background:rgba(255,255,255,0)` after `background:transparent`?

Comment: Yes I've tried that. No dice.